# PostgreSQL Get the previous occurrences

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to generate a query that will give the previous occurrences for the same key.

```
Select load date,  user, account product
from xxx
```

the same key (will be users account product ) exist the previous 3 days

Assuming today, the output would be:

```
20210523 , John, 123456, (20210522,20210521,20210520)
```

How in PostgreSQL can I return the occurrence information?

Sorry for any wrong format, I'm typing in the phone

Best regards,
Paulo Serra

Answer (score 1):

If you want users that existing on the previous three days, you can use:

```
Select user, account product
from xxx
where load_date >= curdate() - interval '2 day'
group by user, account product
having count(distinct load_date::date) = 3;
```

If you really want the dates in the result set, you can include:

```
array_agg(distinct load_date::date)
```

Comment: it works if i dont put the load_date. in my scenario im going to need the date in the statement. In for this particular date, the user and account exists in the previous days 1, 2, 3

Sorry i put the query statement wrongly. i forgot to put the load date in the select